# How to get stories that are "In Progress" for a user using JIRA REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get stories that are just in progress, using userName but it lists all the stories which were assigned to the user.

GET request :
URL - https://jira.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=spruthvi&fields=id,key,status

Is there any possible way to get the stories that are in progress when we search with userName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below rest api query will give the issues that are in - "In Progress" and assigned to a specific user. This is tested on Jira Data centre *V8.13.x*

```html
https://<jira-url>/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=<assigneeID>+AND+status=%22In%20Progress%22+order+by+duedate&fields=id,key
```

For more details refer [Atlassian Example](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this jql in issue navigator first to check whether you get the expected results. Then you can try with REST client.

> assignee== OR reporter == AND status == 'In
> Progress'

In Jira the user is involved in the issue in the form of an assignee or a reporter or a watcher or through any other custom field.